# How does multiplication work when a 3D array is dotted with a 1D array?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, dimensional-analysis

**EDIT: cleaned up as suggested by comments**

I know the shortcut to seeing if a matrix multiplication will work out okay:

[image]

But how does this rule generalize when you have multidimensional arrays? I ran across a situation when doing some computations on images.

I have an array that consists of 2,048 7 x 7 images. So the dims are (7, 7, 2048).

I have an array that is just 2048 scalars. Dims are (2048,).

How come, when I dot these using a standard linear algebra library (numpy, in Python), I get back an array of dims (7, 7)??

I'm trying to think visualize this in my head, and on scratch paper, using the dimension property from the graphic above:
(7 x 7 x 2048)  (2048) --> (7 x 7). Very confusing. I don't understand what action this operation will perform on my 3D volume of image data. I looked at this and thought for sure this couldn't be computed by a basic linear algebra library, but I was wrong.

Here is the problem in python, a quick copypasta and run will explain:

```
import numpy as np
def make_3d_array(dim_x, dim_y, dim_z, val_per_z):
    '''
    this will make a 3D array. Each slice (x, y plane) will have a value you give it, from a list called val_per_z.
    '''
    print(len(val_per_z))
    print(dim_z)
    assert len(val_per_z) == dim_z
    l = []  # store arrays in list
    for n in range(dim_z):  
        two_d_array = np.full((dim_x, dim_y, 1), val_per_z[n])
        l.append(two_d_array)
    a = np.concatenate(l, axis=2)
    return a

val_per_z = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=(2048,))

a = make_3d_array(7,7,2048, val_per_z)
print("here's the shape of my array:", a.shape)

b = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=(2048,))
print("here's the shape of my other array:", b.shape)

ans = a.dot(b)
print("This works, but the dimensions are super confusing! How can you dot a 3D array with a 1D vector and get a 2D result?? Here's the shape:", ans.shape)
```

Comment: $7\times7\times1024$ does not denote the dimension of a matrix, does it ?

Comment: yes, the dims are (7, 7, 1024)

Comment: Hem, three numbers ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust That is a convenient way to print 
 dims when using Python. I hope it is readable.

Comment: Last attempt: isn't a matrix 2D ?

Comment: I thought about this a bit more. You're not doing matrix multiplication (because a $7 \times 7 \times 1024$ array is not a matrix). I think the numpy `dot` function is doing a certain type of tensor product. Here "tensor" just means a multidimensional array of numbers. I think this type of tensor multiplication is explained in Golub and Van Loan, for example, but I'd need to double check. It's a generalization of matrix multiplication. For example, the product of an $m \times n \times k$ tensor and a $k$-tensor (a $k$-element array, that is) is an $m \times n$ tensor.

Comment: Yes...I think I should have referred to it at a tensor. @Yves Daoust was pointing me that direction. I always assumed that multidimensional arrays, when multiplied, followed similar rules as mxn matrices, just in higher dimension. I'm trying to understand those rules.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck: tensor product and matrix product differ or not depending on how you use the Einstein summation convention. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: "How come, when I dot these using a standard linear algebra library (numpy, in Python), I get back an array of dims (7, 7)??" Because that is what the numpy documention says you should get back: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: Sure. But is there anything else to it? Is this a standard mathematical operation? Or is it just some pet function dreamed up by some guy in his underwear in his basement?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck I deleted my answer because I realized that numpy's `dot` function does not actually implement the operation I described (at least not in all cases).